# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, view

I'm struggling to understand why I have this error for the custom uuid text field.

Data:

```
{
            "contact_uuid": "49548747-48888043",
            "choices": "",
            "value": "1",
            "cardType": "TEXT",
            "step": 1,
            "optionId": "",
            "path": "/app/e120703e-2079-4e5f-8420-3924f9e0b9c8/page1/next",
            "title": "Welcome to my app"
        }
```

View:
The important bit here is the line that saves the data so you can gloss over the rest of the code.

```
class NextDialog(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        contact_uuid = data["contact_uuid"]
        step = data["step"]
        value = data["value"]
        optionId = data["optionId"]
        path = get_path(data)
        request = build_rp_request(data)
        app_response = post_to_app(request, path)
        response_data = AppAssessment(contact_uuid, step, value, optionId)
        response_data.save()
        try:
            report_path = app_response["_links"]["report"]["href"]
            response = get_report(report_path)
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        message = format_message(app_response)
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Model:

```
class AppAssessment(models.Model):
    contact_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    step = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    optionId = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_input = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contact_uuid
```

When the response_data.save() line runs in the view, I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/osboxes/ndoh-hub/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 972, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '49548747-48888043'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is the order of arguments. when you call `AppAssessment()` with positional arguments, the order of arguments may not be what you expect. so calling `AppAssessment()` with keyword arguments may solve the problem.

replace this line:

```py
response_data = AppAssessment(contact_uuid, step, value, optionId)
```

with this:

```py
response_data = AppAssessment(contact_uuid=contact_uuid, step=step, optionId=optionId, user_input=value)
```

I am not sure which attribute you wanted to use `value` for. but I guess it was   `user_input`.